# password change api with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There is no error in the codes I wrote, but the password of the user who receives the mail does not change. The password that changes is only the password of the first user in the users table. No matter what I tried, I could not succeed.

Api.php

```
Route::post('/forgetPassword',[UserController::class,'forgetPassword']);
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/resetPassword',[UserController::class,'forgetPasswordLoad']);
Route::post('/resetPassword',[UserController::class,'resetPassword']);
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\PasswordReset;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;



class UserController extends Controller
{

  
    #reset password
    public function forgetPassword(Request $request)
        {
        try {
            $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->get();
            
            if (count($user)>0) {
                $token = Str::random(40);
                $domain = URL::to('/');
                $url = $domain.'/resetPassword?token='.$token;

                $data['url']=$url;
                $data['email']=$request->email;
                $data['title']="Password Reset";
                $data['body']="Please click on below link to reset password";

                Mail::send('API/forgetPasswordMail',['data'=>$data],function($message) use ($data){
                    $message->to($data['email'])->subject($data['title']);
                });

                $datetime = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                PasswordReset::updateOrCreate(
                ['email'=>$request->email],
                [
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'token' => $token,
                    'created_at' =>$datetime
                ]
                );

                return response()->json(['success'=>true,'message'=>'Şifrenizi değiştirmek için lütfen mailinizi kontrol ediniz!']);


            }else {
                return response()->json(['success'=>false,'message'=>'Kullanıcı Bulunamadı']);
            }



        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['success'=>false,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
        }
        }
    #reset password view load
    public function forgetPasswordLoad(Request $request) 
        {
        $resetData = PasswordReset::where('token',$request->token)->get();
        if (count($resetData)>0) {

            $user = User::where('email',$resetData[0]['email'])->get();
            return view('API/resetPassword',compact('user'));

        }else {
            return view('API/404');
        }
        }
   
    #reset password func
    public function resetPassword(Request $request)
        {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
            ]);
    
            $user = User::find($request->id);
            $user->password =$request->password;
            $user->save();
            return "<h1>Şifreniz Başarıyla Değiştirildi.Mobil Uygulamaya Dönebilirsiniz</h1>";
        }  catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['success'=>false,'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
        }

        // PasswordReset::where('email',$user->email)->delete();

    
        }
   
    }
```

resetPassword.blade.php

```
        <h1>Proxima Doktor</h1>
        <form method="POST">
               @csrf
                <h3>Password Reset</h3>
                <p>Lütfen güçlü bir parola giriniz</p>
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user[0]['id']}}">
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                <p>Password Again</p>
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
                <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

PasswordReset.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PasswordReset extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'password_reset_tokens';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'email';


    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'token',
        'created_at'
 
    ];
}
```

I have shared all my related files, thank you if anyone can help.

Comment: When the person goes through the Forget Password process, does that person get the reset link email? Does the link look correct? It should have the correct User ID or email in the link. A lot of the lookups you're using should be unique, so you should use `->first()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: Laravel has it's own [password reset methods](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords#reset-email-customization), you don't need to create your own

Comment: Yes, it receives the mail. correct in the e-mail at the link he received

Comment: I wanted to try it. But I will look into that method.

Comment: the link you shared says it is valid for old laravel versions. Does it still work?

Comment: I linked the 9x version, which came out last year. Laravel 10 came out last month. The information will still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking your code in the model, you miss one thing, you aren't putting the password attribute inside the protected $fillable variable.

Try doing this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'token',
    'created_at',
    'password'
];
```

Also, maybe you don't need to put the created_at variable inside de array.

Comment: If you do not specify it, you cannot change the password.

Comment: I don't need to keep the password value in that table, I just use this table to distinguish the user.
When I made created_at as the primaryKey, I got the result I wanted and my code worked. But do you mind if I do this?

Comment: `fillable` is only necessary when doing a create/update call. Doing `$user->password = 'something'; $user->save();` does not require a fillable attribute.

Comment: I understood what you said. But when I add the password, the same result is obtained.

Comment: created_at as a primary key? @mehmetozdemir why?

Comment: `created_at` should NOT be the primary key. The Users table has an `id` for a reason

Comment: @aynber has reason

Comment: because when i do it that way it works fine